# Select those emails from db if they wanted to get an email

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2014-express

I am developing a system that heavily relies on emailing, I'm trying to determine if users wanted to get notified or not.

User details are stored in SQL Server Express. I want to check which registered users wanted to receive and get their emails from the database. Is this possible?

So far I got this far:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [UserTable] WHERE ([price] = @price)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", "10.000");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error is SQL DB: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

It returns -1, but I have a 10.000 in one row. And from here I want to save the email addresses of those who has 10.000 on their preferences from the db so I can add it to email list.

So to summarize: Check all rows if some of them has 'yes' and save their 'email' from the same row.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thank you.

---

### Updated it for @SeM

```
private void getMailList()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-9MMTAI1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserTable WHERE price = @price";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", 10000));
                int count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error is SQL DB: " + ex);
            //Handle your exception;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is not the write thing to call here.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returning the number of rows that affected.

Comment: And instead of writing `try{} catch{} finally{}` (in your case), just use `using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)){}`

Comment: Just out of curiousity, and sorry if this is out of scope, why are you using a Price column to determine if a person wants to receive emails or not?  Isn't that the job of a boolean field?

Comment: No that was just an example, the fields are not english so I changed them to price, but yes they are numeric values, if thats what you are asking. @DanielAtwood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returning the number of rows that affected only for `Update`, `Insert` and `Delete` statements. In your case, you will always get get `-1`, because on Select statement `ExecuteNonQuery` returning `-1`

So try this:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserTable WHERE price = @price";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", 10000));
            int count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar());         
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle your exception;   
    }
}
```

Comment: And you should also put your `SqlCommand` into a `using(....) { ... }` block, really....

Comment: 'command.ExecuteScalar' is giving an error: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'string'. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @C.S.I've updated your `Updated it for @SeM` code, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, ExecuteNonQuery does just that - no query results.

Instead:

```
int recordsAffected = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```